Next.js SWR-like behavior with Streaming SSR & PPR
I am building a data-intensive app at my company. There are multiple pages, including

/experiment - lists all experiments, data updated couple times an hour
/experiment/[id] - metadata on the experiment, data updated couple times an minute
/experiment/[id]/log - logs on the experiment, data updated couple times a second
etc

Previously, we were not updating the website and provided a refresh button, with logs getting streamed with Firebase on client-side.
We now have a great opportunity to rebuild this app, and we want to make it as futureproof as possible. Thus, we are investigating two ways to handle data more declaratively.

SWR
Next.js RSC

In the end, we think using Next.js RSC will have more benefits onwards, with PPR and more features to come. However, in order to revalidate and update the results, especially on the /experiment/[id] page, we are not sure of how to approach this, without much reinventing-the-wheel problem.. Normally using SWR will automatically solve this problem with minimal boilerplate.
Hopefully, I am expecting where the initial data gets loaded and rendered on the server-side, then served through Streaming SSR or PPR, then the client-side can hydrate and take over, thus providing SWR-like capabilities, such as optimistic updates and polling, revalidate-on-focus, etc.
I know I can use

revalidatePath("/...") to do a full re-render
revalidateTag directive to re-fetch a certain fetch on the server
fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 3600 } }) to periodically update data on the server

...but none of the features seem to work as I described: PPR benefits on load, SWR benefits thereafter.
I tried looking at

Building Your Application: Caching | Next.js
How to Revalidate Server Components in Next.js 13th?


SOLUTION: I eventually figured out that you can first make a generic fetch that could be shared both on SWR and Server, then you

fetch on server
pass that data as props to a client component
the client will mount that data to fallback of SWR
and use SWR states for isLoading. You could optionally use suspense: true to make the code even more sharable.

Note: https://youtu.be/9jqPbNgzHOA?si=TM9pqiy4Z-cFQBr8&t=1859

Use Next.js RSC to fetch and render the initial data on the server side. This will allow you to take advantage of server-side rendering benefits, such as faster initial load times and better SEO.
Once the initial data is loaded and rendered on the server, you can use SWR on the client side to handle data fetching and revalidation. SWR will allow you to get features like polling, optimistic updates, and revalidation on focus.
To set this up, you can start by using Next.js getServerSideProps to fetch the initial data for your pages. For example, on your /experiment/[id] page, you would fetch the experiment metadata on the server side and pass it as props to your component.
And in your React component, you can use SWR to fetch the same data on the client side. SWR will handle the revalidation and keep your data up-to-date without requiring a full page refresh.

I'm sorry but with all due respect this does not answer the question. This question was on how EXACTLY this could work, not about the generic concepts.
